# moongoose js Schema is not a Constructor and function error

Tags: node.js, mongodb, schema, mongoose-schema

I am facing a problem with moongoose js

This is my node js code:

```
var mongoose=require('moongoose');
var test=mongoose.Schema({test:String})
module.exports = mongoose.model('test',test);
```

When I run this code, node js throws:

```
var test=mongoose.Schema({test:String})
         ^
TypeError: **mongoose.Schema is not a function**
at Object.<anonymous> (H:\TodoList\Model\TodoListModel.js:4:19)
at Module._compile (module.js:652:30)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:663:10)
at Module.load (module.js:565:32)
at tryModuleLoad (module.js:505:12)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:497:3)
at Module.require (module.js:596:17)
at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
at Object.<anonymous> (H:\TodoList\app.js:9:10)
at Module._compile (module.js:652:30)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:663:10)
at Module.load (module.js:565:32)
at tryModuleLoad (module.js:505:12)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:497:3)
at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:693:10)
at startup (bootstrap_node.js:188:16)
```

If I change this code to this format:

```
var mongoose=require('moongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
var test=new Schema({test:String})
module.exports = mongoose.model('test',test);
```

That code throws:

```
TypeError: **Schema is not a constructor**
```

Please help me to resolve this code error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its `require('mongoose');` you have written `require('moongoose');`

an `o` typo :))